# Sorting a meta-list by first element of children lists in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-2.x

I have a list, `root`, of lists, `root[child0]`, `root[child1]`, etc.

I want to sort the children of the root list by the first value in the child list, `root[child0][0]`, which is an `int`.

Example:

```
import random
children = 10
root = [[random.randint(0, children), "some value"] for child in range(children)]
```

I want to sort `root` from greatest to least by the first element of each of it's children.

I've taken a look at some previous entries that used `sorted()` and a `lamda` function I'm entirely unfamiliar with, so I'm unsure of how to apply that to my problem.

Appreciate any direction that can by given

Thanks

Comment: Do you not get a `TypeError: int is not iterable`?

Comment: my mistake, fixed the code above. children now iterable through range()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may specify a [`key` function](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/#Key_Functions) which will determine the sorting order.

```
sorted(root, key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)
```

You said you aren't familiar with lambdas. Well, first off, [you can read this](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk). Then, I'll give you the skinny: the lambda is an anonymous function (unless you assign it to a variable, a la `f = lambda x: x[0]`) which takes the form [`lambda arguments: expression`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda). The `expression` is what is returned by the lambda. So the key function here takes one argument, `x`, and returns `x[0]`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response and the links, works perfectly

Comment: @thismachinechills Glad it helped - check out Ashwini's answer for the `itemgetter` which will increase your performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can the `key` parameter to specify the function or item you want to use for comparing the items.

```
key = lambda x : x[0]
```

or better : `key = operator.itemgetter(0)`

or you can also define your own function if necessary and pass it to `key`.

```
>>> root = [[random.randint(0, children), "some value"] for child in range(children)]
>>> root
[[3, 'some value'], [8, 'some value'], [5, 'some value'], [4, 'some value'], [3, 'some value'], [3, 'some value'], [2, 'some value'], [5, 'some value'], [5, 'some value'], [4, 'some value']]
>>> root.sort(key = lambda x : x[0], reverse = True)
>>> root
[[8, 'some value'], [5, 'some value'], [5, 'some value'], [5, 'some value'], [4, 'some value'], [4, 'some value'], [3, 'some value'], [3, 'some value'], [3, 'some value'], [2, 'some value']]
```

or using `operator.itemgetter`:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> root.sort(key = itemgetter(0), reverse = True)
>>> root
[[8, 'some value'], [5, 'some value'], [5, 'some value'], [5, 'some value'], [4, 'some value'], [4, 'some value'], [3, 'some value'], [3, 'some value'], [3, 'some value'], [2, 'some value']]
```

Comment: @2rs2ts yes, just tested for 10**5 items: `lambda` : 1.01 sec, `itemgetter`: 750 ms.

Answer (score 0):

That's the reverse of how Python sorts by default, so the `key` argument is unnecessary in this case - you can just use the `reverse` argument in isolation...

```
>>> import random
>>> import pprint
>>> root = [[random.randint(0, children), "some value"] for child in range(children)]
>>> pprint.pprint(root)
[[0, 'some value'],
 [2, 'some value'],
 [3, 'some value'],
 [1, 'some value'],
 [1, 'some value'],
 [1, 'some value'],
 [3, 'some value'],
 [7, 'some value'],
 [7, 'some value'],
 [8, 'some value']]
>>> root.sort(reverse=True)
>>> pprint.pprint(root)
[[8, 'some value'],
 [7, 'some value'],
 [7, 'some value'],
 [3, 'some value'],
 [3, 'some value'],
 [2, 'some value'],
 [1, 'some value'],
 [1, 'some value'],
 [1, 'some value'],
 [0, 'some value']]
```